# Does it make sense to have getters and setters on a static, or just make it public

Tags: java, scope

I have a `static double` that other classes will need to access and modify.

Does it make sense to have a `public` getter and setter and make the `static double` `private`

or, just make the `static double` `public`?

For non-`static` members, i can see benefit in setters and getters, but i'm not sure for 
`static`s.

Comment: I would say for convention, documentation and consistency purposes you should use getters and setters.

Comment: Always or never, depending on your religion.

Comment: Since there are really only two possibilities it seemed that this would not be subject to endless speculation, so can it please be taken off hold?  I am really interested to see more experts state their decision logic.

Answer (score 2):

Use getters and setters, because it is more flexible. It also can prevent someone changing the `double` to something that is not allowed in your application. You can just check that in your getting and setting methods. Also it is easier to document. Please do use getters, and setters.

Answer (score 1):

The rote answers have been given and they are correct as far as they go: public classes are bad (unless final). Instead, you should always grant access through methods so you have some control over the development of the class.

The real design question is, why do you want to allow other classes to have access to this class's data in the first place? There are a few specific cases where this makes sense, and many more cases where it does not. Roughly speaking, if a class is a data bag, you want to allow users to put data in and get it out. Otherwise, you pretty much want to let the class handle its own business. That is, we submit data to an object and maybe get a response. We don't reach in and examine and set its values, because if we're doing that we're creating needless coupling.

I would encourage you to revisit your design and think again about the need to write spaghetti code. This will probably bite you later on. Instead, try to come up with a design that "carves nature at its joints" - that is, one where you don't need to reach across cell walls in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use getter and setter because you can later add synchronization or perform additional actions when you modify the variable in case you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a setter/getter iff that variable is `static` but not `final` and you have to validate it when a new value is set, and it's probably you have to make that methods `synchronized` if you are in a multithread context.